# How to get tkinter menubar label Value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have looked a lot but can`t find the answer, below is an example:

```
Menu.add_command(label='abc',command=callback)
```

How can I get this 'abc' for variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`entrycget()`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/menu.htm#M54)    and pass to it the "label" option.

Here is a short example to demonstrate how it works:

```
import tkinter as tk


def callback(menu):
    x= menu.entrycget(0, "label")
    print(x) # This will print "abc" in your Terminal


root = tk.Tk()
menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)
file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
file_menu.add_command(label="abc", command=lambda: callback(file_menu))
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems that x= menu.entrycget(0, "label") the index '0' locks the print result ,if I have sevral menu commands ,how can I get the right index from entrycget when I click the 'abc01' , 'abc02' or 'abc03i'command ?Thax for answer~

Comment: That is easy, just loop over them, for example if you have 4 elements, rung this: `for index in range(0,4): print( menu.entrycget(index, "label"))` @LanYu

Comment: If I click 'abc03' command, how to return the index of 'abc03' command?

Comment: I mean if I make a loop,it would show all the command labels..If I just want get one of them,how to return it`s index? Thx again

Answer (score 1):

I solved ur problem. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

def callback(menu):
    for index in range(0,1): print( menu.entrycget(0, "label"))
    
def callback1(menu1):
    for index in range(1, 2): print( menu1.entrycget(1, "label"))
    
def callback2(menu):
    for index in range(2,3): print( menu.entrycget(2, "label"))
    
def callback3(menu):
    for index in range(3,4): print( menu.entrycget(3, "label"))
    
def callback4(menu):
    for index in range(4,4): print( menu.entrycget(4, "label"))
    
root = Tk() 
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=lambda: callback(filemenu))
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=lambda: callback1(filemenu))
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=lambda: callback2(filemenu))
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=lambda: callback3(filemenu))
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=None)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```